# How do I use "text_dataset_from_directory" to do binary text classification from tf.dataset object?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

Sorry, I am still relatively new to text classification and Tensorflow, so this may look like a very dumb question.

I have the song lyrics of two different singers. What I am trying to achieve is to build a binary text classification model to predict whether a song fits to the style of singer A or singer B more.
I have the training data (the lyrics text files) of both classes in sub-directories. The directory structure is similar to,

```
Classification/
...Singer_A/
......A_song_1.txt
......A_song_2.txt
...Singer_B/
......B_song_1.txt
......B_song_2.txt
```

And from what I read on the Tensorflow documentation, I could easily construct a dataset by using the
`text_dataset_from_directory` method. So something like,

```
dataset = text_dataset_from_directory(
    'Classification', labels='inferred', label_mode='int',
    batch_size=32
)
```

However, I don't know how I could go on from there. I would suppose that the created `tf.data.Dataset` object would still need Tokenization in the texts component, and the tokenized text would then need padding and embedding before feeding it into a logistic model. But I don't know how to further process it in the `tf.data.Dataset` object.

I saw [Tensorflow's Text Embedding Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/guide/word_embeddings), but don't really see how it could be changed to become a binary model.

Answer (score 0):

For a given directory structure

```
Classification/
...Singer_A/
......A_song_1.txt
......A_song_2.txt
...Singer_B/
......B_song_1.txt
......B_song_2.txt
```

Prepare dataset for binary classification `text_dataset_from_directory`

```
import tensorflow as tf
batch_size = 32
seed = 42
#training dataset
raw_train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    'classificatio/', 
    batch_size=batch_size, 
    validation_split=0.2, 
    subset='training', 
    seed=seed)
#validation dataset
raw_val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    'aclImdb/train', 
    batch_size=batch_size, 
    validation_split=0.2, 
    subset='validation', 
    seed=seed)
```

Once the train ad validation dataset is ready perform the data text preprocessing such as tokenization, make it lowercase, removing special character and vectorization. Using below sample code

```
def custom_standardization(input_data):
  lowercase = tf.strings.lower(input_data)
  stripped_html = tf.strings.regex_replace(lowercase, '<br />', ' ')
  return tf.strings.regex_replace(stripped_html,
                                  '[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation),
                                  '')
```

Refer the basic [text binary classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification) for more information.